# How can I detect on flutter application is killed or terminated

Tags: flutter

I want to safely close some process before my flutter application is terminated.
I tried with didChangeAppLifecycleState but detached never called.
How can I detect that my application will stop?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: maybe try to use ondestroy() method or refer to this code https://pastebin.com/2MVgTsXV  .this is my way using didChangeAppLifeCycleState() method.

Comment: @khoi I've tried this but the problem is I want to let my process do in background if user just swap the application (inactive / pause), and kill this process on application terminated. and found no lifecycle hooked on this state